# Upload,read and display the image with Tkinter and Opencv-Python

Tags: python, tkinter, opencv3.0

I want to upload this file using tkinter method and read it using cv2.imread and display .But i have a problem,this is the code i am using:

```
wid=Tk()
def myown():
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=wid,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
   data = file.read()
   b=cv2.imread(data)
   cv2.imshow('img',b)
   cv2.waitKey(0)

   file.close()
```

after this,

```
  wid3=Button(None,text="upload it",command=myown)
  wid.mainloop
```

but i am getting an opencv error,the image is not being displayed by the imshow,it says size.width>0 && size.height>0

Comment: what is the _exact_ error?

Comment: where do you ant to display `file`? You don't need OpenCV for a simply Tkinter display, if that's the only thing you want to do

Comment: No,its an Opencv project,I'm doing image processing so i need to use OpenCV @BillalBEGUERADJ

Comment: The error is,I am not able to read the image itself @BryanOakley

Comment: Why can't you open it? Are you getting an error? What error?